# How to put html href button inside php code

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to put an html href button inside of my php code, but when I run it, I get an error message saying "This Page Isn't Working."

```
<?php

echo "<button onclick="location.href='phpfile.php';">My Button</button>";

?>
```

Comment: try ```window.location```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to escape the `HTML` double quotes:

```
echo "<button onclick=\"location.href='phpfile.php';\">My Button</button>";
```

Or the Javascript single quotes:

```
echo '<button onclick="location.href=\'phpfile.php\';">My Button</button>';
```

By the way,

> This Page Isn't Working.

Means a 500 error, which means your `php` script does not compile. Most of the time it is due to syntax errors.